# How to check if UIImage from assets is fully loaded

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimage, uiviewanimationtransition

In a viewcontroller I have two image views on top of each other and two buttons labelled previous and next.

I have an array of `UIImage`s

```
let images = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2"), UIImage(named: "3")]
```

I have this helper method to transition to the next image by fading

```
func changeImage(image: UIImage){
self.topImageView.alpha = 0 //This is to initially make the next image to fade in
self.topImageView.image = image
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in 
self.topImageView.alpha = 1.0  //this will fade in the next image
}) { (Bool) -> Void in
    self.bottomImageView.image = image //Previous image will be replaced with the now current image after fade
    }
}
```

I attached this helper method on the prev and next buttons to cycle through the images

The problem now is whenever I tap the button, the fade animation does not work and just simply loads the image on the bottomImageView. But when I go tap previous, the fade works.

I believe the reason why it does this is because the next image is still loading for the first time, then when trying to go back to it, the fade will work eventually.

So how do you load the images beforehand so the fade animation would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend moving away from the two overlaying `UIImageView`s and simply to use one. Then you can use the following code to change the image animated:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.topImageView, duration: 0.5, options: [.TransitionCrossDissolve], animations: { () -> Void in
    self.topImageView.image = image
    }) { completed in
        print("transition finished")
}
```

Two imageViews only introduce unwanted problems (as your question clearly shows). And one view is simply a lot cleaner.

Regarding your theory as to why your code does not work as intended: I have not heard of image loading taking any noticeable amount of time - there has to be something else wrong. For example is your `topImageView` ***really*** on top of the other view?

Comment: Thanks! Got it.
Found out that for some reason this bug is in the iPhone 4S, but on 5 and newer does not show the problem I'm having.